# How to get touch event for whole application instead of only activity

Tags: android, touch

Is there a way to override method such as `onTouchEvent()` in application class in order to get x/y coordinates of touch or motion event among all activities in app. I know I can implement `onTouchEvent()` in activity but I want to avoid putting that method in all activities. I know I can make activity class in which I can implement `onTouchEvent()` and extend thats class in all activities but that is not sufficient for me. If you have any suggestions please let me know.